# Power BI Create Continuous Line Chart at End of Position

Tags: charts, powerbi, dax, linechart, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a line chart which the dark blue line data point ends halfway through the chart, as no future data is yet available.

Is there a way to continue the line throughout the rest of the months on the date X Axis as a straight line with its current end position?

Current measure reads

```
Actuals = SELECTEDVALUE('Actual Hours'[Average Actual FTE])​
```

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4JZ1.png)

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbiaY.png)

EDIT

[Updated Line Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHR2g.png)
[New Measure Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk7eT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue the line you should fill blanks for future dates like this:

```
Actuals = 
VAR _LastDate =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Table'[month]),
        ALL('Table'),
        NOT(ISBLANK('Table'[value]))
    )
VAR _Value =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[value]),
        'Table'[month] = _LastDate
    )
RETURN
SWITCH(
    SUM('Table'[value]),
    BLANK(), _Value,
    SUM('Table'[value])
)
```

*_LastDate* defines last date with non-blank value and *_Value* gets value for this date. Inside *RETURN* we fill blanks with *_Value* and do nothing to non-blanks.

On my dummy data it looks like:
[image]

Comment: This is great! however, it rolls up figures into totals (See new screenshots in original post) i also have a separate date and forecast table which is linked which maybe causing this issue?

Comment: Why are you using date table inside measure? It's not necessary. Use Date column from your fact table. Also, you can decompose this measure into separate measures (1 variable - 1 measure), add them into table with other data and try to understand on which step complex measure returns wrong result.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it to work :)

Comment: Nice! Then vote up for my answer and mark it as correct if you don't mind.